# Get selected option value from select in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get selected option from select in popup window, with Jquery. Inside popup which I created with var popup = window.open etc. I have select populated with options, and later I am trying to access selected value like this but can not get it. What is the right way?

```
var element = '<br><select id="' + item.product_option_id +'" class="form-control">';
```

Then later I am trying to access selected option with this:

```
console.log(popup.document.$('#'+item.product_option_id+' option:selected').val());
```

Comment: What you have should work, although you can get the `val()` of the `select` directly We need to see more of your JS code to help you. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Use: `$(popup.document.body).find("#" + item.product_option_id+').val();`

Comment: @karacsi_maci That should probably be an answer instead of a comment. Cheerios!

Comment: wow @karacsi_maci your ma men ! thanks

Comment: @Nikanor I had a syntax error, no need the `+'` after the variable name. See the answer of @moopet

Answer (score 1):

You have to figure out what `popup.document.$` is supposed to represent.

It's not likely to be anything (although without the rest of your code we can't be sure).

`$` is an alias for the jQuery object, and it's not a property of the `document` - if you want to be specific, it's a property of the `window` object, but in practice people don't worry about that.

If you want to access the popup's document, you're right in using `popup.document`, but you can't hang jQuery off it like that - the jQuery object takes a selector just like normal, so use:

```
$(popup.document.body)
```

as the top level of your other window, then you can use any of the normal jQuery functions such as `find()`, or you can use this handy syntax:

```
$('#my-selector', $(popup.document.body))
```

instead.